# Read a specific selection of multiple unique variables from a netcdf file into python

Tags: python, file-io, batch-processing, netcdf

I am fairly new to python.  I have an output from a 3-D coupled biogeochemical-hydrodynamic model, and the data are in netcdf4 format.  Each netcdf file contains ~130 unique 3-D variables, and I want to read a selection of those variables into python so I can afterward manipulate, slice, average etc. the subset.  Each variable name & variable is a dictionary key-value pair.   I think there should be a way to read a selection of these variables, for example by selecting a subset of variable values to read based on their dictionary keys (the variables I want to read all have the same prefix eg. zoo1, zoo2, zoo3), but I cannot find such a method in the cdms2 or netcdf4 tutorial literature.  The only thing I can find is to reference every variable I want to read one at a time, for example:

import cdms2

f = cdms2.open('filename.nc')

zoo1 = f['zoo1']

That would be beyond tedious since I want to read 80 variables all with the same prefix. I would also be open to doing a batch read of all variables at once if anyone knows how to approach that, although it is less ideal than being able to choose my subset. The file contains more than just variables so I don't think I can do a batch read on the entire file (if that is even possible).  Suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by import? If you're using the netCDF4 module, they should all be accessible once you load the file via the `Dataset` function. E.g. `nc=Dataset("yourncfile.nc"); nc.variables['zoo1']`, etc. Why do you need to store each one as a new variable?

Comment: I found an answer by looking through several different old posts.  Hopefully it helps others.  `d=f.variables`  # import the entire dictionary called 'variables' (all variables in the netcdf file)
`old_keys = d.keys()` # All the keys of the dictionary in a list
`wanted_keys = [name for name in old_keys if name.find('zoo') == 0]`  # select only wanted keys by a string selector (in my case, the 'zoo' prefix), using list comprehension
`newd = dict([(i, d[i]) for i in wanted_keys if i in d])`  # use wanted_keys to create new dictionary containing only the wanted key-value subset.